# Undo a Mistake made while squashing the commits in GIT

Tags: git, github

I wanted to squash my last 2 commits into one, so did a `git rebase`, in following way:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

but due to a typo, what I **actually** ended up pushing into origin was:

```
git rebase -i HEAD-3
```

Now, in the [Github Pull Request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5815#commits-pushed-06674f0) it shows commit of some other unrelated commit. so basically, I want to remove commit `06674f0` which isn't mine, while keeping `fcea5e0` in this PR.

how to fix the mess caused by simple typo?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Edit: Check your reflog with

```
git reflog
```

Pick the commit previous to your first rebase and replace the x with appropriate number below:

Just undo your last rebase and redo it:

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{x}
git rebase -i HEAD~2
..
git push -f origin master
```

Remove your pull request and issue a new one.

Comment: Yeah it probably can. I was just thinking that you might want to remove it while you are working with it.

Comment: I tried it but didn't work. Instead of the two commit I wanted to merge were lost & now trying to run `git rebase -i HEAD~2` picks up two commits from further back in history

Comment: Edited my answer. HEAD^ was wrong of me. Use gits reflog to pick the appropriate HEAD. Note HEAD{x} where x is shosen from the reflog.

Comment: This is also helpful in explaining this: http://jacopretorius.net/2012/11/squashing-the-wrong-commit-in-git.html

Comment: I'm generally not a "+1" kind of guy, but after included the commit of another contributor in my PR, I was very glad to find this helpful question, and more for its perfect answer.

Comment: `git reset --hard HEAD{x}` didnt work for me. I had to run `git reset --hard HEAD@{x}`

Comment: FWIW, _x_ here would be something like 2,3,4, etc present in reflog itself and not the commit ID. Spent some time figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

Both `git reset --hard HEAD{x}` and `git reset --hard HEAD@{x}` didn't work for me.

I wanted a script to do this anyways, so I did the following.

```
BACK_2_SHA=`git reflog show --pretty=format:'%H' -n x | tail -n 1`
git reset --hard $BACK_2_SHA
```